# Divide numbers into equal parts to create Sitemap from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I need something like below

If total number is 2990 , and i want to divide it by 500 equal parts .For example output should be like below stored in **array**

```
0,500
500,1000
1000,1500
1500,2000
2000,2500
2500,2990
```

What I tried

```
  for($i=0;$i<=2990;$i=$i+500)
    {

if($i%500==0)
{
$var = array_push($var,$i,$+500);
}

   }
```

P.s : I am creating a sitemap and I need something like this to create LIMIT in my mysql query

Comment: Is this a question about pagination?

Comment: Sounds a pretty unwieldy approach to pagination to me, but just build one big array and then use `$array = array_chunk($array, 500);`

Comment: No  , Its grabbing all the data seperated with equal parts

Comment: why -3 ? whats wrong in this question -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$part_size = 500;
$limit = 2990;

for($i=0;$i<=$limit;$i=$i+$part_size)
{
    $j = $i + $part_size;
    if($j > $limit) {
        $j = $limit;    
    }
    $resultArray[] = $i.','.$j;
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
for($i=0;$i<=2990;$i=$i+500)
{
    if($i +500 < 2900) $array[] = $i.",".($i+500);
    else $array[] = $i.","."2900";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mod function along with a basic loop to get what you want (if I understand it correctly) like this:

```
<?php

    $total=2990;
    // Example of results counted.
    $remainder=$total%500;
    // Remainder after all complete sections have been used.
    for($i=0;$i<floor($total/500);$i++)
    {
        // Push each section of 500 into your new array;
    }
    // push $remainder last elements of original array into new array?
    // Maybe something using $i*500 to get the 
    //starting point and $remainder to get the exact number?
?>
```