# How to pass array value in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

With the help of to this question, "[Divide numbers into equal parts to create Sitemap from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397576/divide-numbers-into-equal-parts-to-create-sitemap-from-mysql/27397708#27397708)", I got this result:

```
Array ( [0] => 0,500 
        [1] => 500,1000 
        [2] => 1000,1500 
        [3] => 1500,2000 
        [4] => 2000,2500 
        [5] => 2500,2990 )
```

My question is, I want to pass the above Array values to select query limit. like this:

```
 "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `rec_id`='1' limit 0 OFFSET 500 "
```

and so on upto `limit 2500, 2990`.

How to do this? I am new to development. please help me with the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this some sort of pagination?

Comment: while looping in outside array, u can explode innner array or u can multiply the index with 500 and u will have starting index.

Comment: @RiggsFolly not like pagination. I want to send mails in group. so for this i have created group of 500 contacts. and fetching 500 email address from table . but i am confused how to use it in query?

Comment: You need to start by creating the array correctly so you get `[0] => 0,500, [1] => 501,500,......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){

  list($limit, $offset) = explode(','$v);

   $query_arr[] = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `rec_id`='1' limit $limit OFFSET $offset";
}
```

And then fire $query_arr as you want

Answer (score 2):

Actually you want a pagination with 500 results begining at an index, right ? So limit should always be 500, only offset value should change.

```
$queries = [];
$array = Array ( [0] => 0,500 
    [1] => 500,1000 
    [2] => 1000,1500 
    [3] => 1500,2000 
    [4] => 2000,2500 
    [5] => 2500,2990 );

foreach ( $array as $value ){
    $offsets = explode(',', $value);
    $queries[] = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `rec_id`='1' limit 500 OFFSET $offsets[0]";
}
```